# How to Serialize Dictionary<string[],int> to json using JsonConvert newtonsoft c#

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, jsonconvert

Trying to serialize `Dictionary<string[],int>`

```
var requestData = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
   { "games" ,new Dictionary<string[],int> { {new string[] { "1000"}, 1 } } }
             
};

var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData);
```

The output `JSON` looks something like
`{"games":{"(Array)":1}}` which is not what I want. Info of `string[]` is gone

Comment: JSON keys have to be string. I think there's no way to store an array as JSON key

Comment: You want X. You thought “serialize Dictionary<string[],int>” would X. Now you discover that won't X. You need to [tell us what X is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use this:

```
var requestData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
         { "games",new Dictionary<int, string[]>{ {  1, new string[] { "1000", "2000"} } }
         }
       };

        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData);
```

it results

```
{"games":{"1":["1000","2000"]}}
```

Comment: Doesn't this have a completely different meaning?